# Use Component from Form

Tags: components, cakephp-3.0

I would like to pass request-data to this form-class to validate generic information. I've implemented a component (outsourced for reusability) to bring address data into required model format.

```
namespace App\Form;

use Cake\Form\Form;
use Cake\Form\Schema;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class Foo extends Form {
    protected function _buildSchema(Schema $schema) {
        return $schema
                    ->addField('foo', 'string')
                    ->addField('bar', 'string');
    }
    [...]
    protected function _execute(array $data) {
        // How is it possible to use component-method here?
        // e.g. $this->MyAddressComponent->saveData($data);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Has anyone an idea what I have to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You most probably shouldn't make a form require a component, components are for controllers, and introducing such a dependency will probably just make testing more complicated. In order for someone to give you a proper advice, it would be good if you'd share a little more context, ie what functionality is it, why do controllers as well as forms need it, etc...

Comment: You can set your view to the form like $this->view->form = new Foo(); in your controller to do something. And as I am writing this answer I realize I am expressing the same thing as the first comment.

Comment: @Blkc This is not about forms in views, but about [**modelless forms](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/form.html)**.

Comment: So you are using the modelless form to validate data, wich has been formatted by a component, and should be sent back to the component after validation where it is then being saved via the model layer?

Comment: @npm Oh I was confused because I thought the OP was asking how to use the form he set up in the component.

Answer (score 1):

Make your form accept the component in the constructor:

```
namespace App\Form;

use App\Controller\Component\MyAddressComponent;

class Foo extends Form {

    private $addressComponent;

    public function __constructor(MyAddressComponent $addressComponent)
    {
        $this->addressComponenent = $addressComponent;
    }

    ...

    protected function _execute(array $data) {
        $this->addressComponent->saveData($data);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then instantiate the form from the controller as follows:

```
public function doStuff()
{
    $form = new Foo($this->MyAddressComponent);
    ...
}
```